# Force user to declare variables in Java

Tags: java, interface, abstract

So, I've been looking at abstract classes and interfaces in Java, and I'd like to know if there's a way (that possibly uses neither?) to force users to declare variables with certain names.

I'm working with annotations, so the goal would be to make some interface or abstract thing like this:

```
public interface Foo{
    Integer x;
    Double y;
}
```

Then I'd want the user to fill it out, with those variable types(although type is optional, as long as it has the name) and names, annotated in the way they want them annotated. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible, and most of the time not desirable.
You can, however, provide methods as a way to access these abstract properties:

```
public interface Foo{
    Integer x(); // get
    void x(Integer x); // set
    Double y();
    void y(Double y);
}
```

Instead of

```
System.out.println(foo.x);
foo.x = 42;
```

you'd now use

```
System.out.println(foo.x());
foo.x(42);
```

Or the more traditional, but also more verbose, naming:

```
public interface Foo{
    Integer getX();
    void setX(Integer x);
    Double getY();
    void setY(Double y);
}
```

Comment: Indeed the second approach seems very more meaningful.

Comment: @mok: Agreed, but the first is just shorter. OP wanted physical fields, and the first is as near to that as it gets in Java. `foo.x` » `foo.x()` and `foo.x = 42` » `foo.x(42)`.

Comment: Yes, the first one seems closer to what the OP wants but indeed the right (better) solution is the second one for which I up voted this answer.

Comment: Well again the idea of doing this would be for me to read the annotations using reflection, but to control the names of the fields the user is putting annotations on. It's for information flow tracking, so the subject of the annotation really does have to be data members, and not methods.

Comment: @user3475234: Then I consider your question quite opaque in respect to that topic. You can always cause a compilation error from within the annotation processor, when the fields don't fulfill your criteria. Update your question, maybe with an example, and I'll see what I can do.